# Unable to upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04

Tags: upgrade

I have been trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 without success it fails to complete. Running the update-manager from terminal give the following when the upgrade fails. 
From searching it appears that this is related to python issues. As my knowledge of linux/ubuntu is limited I’m asking for help/guidance in how to resolve the issue so I can upgrade successfully i.e what I can check logs etc or commands to issue for clues to pinpoint the problem I have.

Messages displayed when upgrade fails:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
authenticate 'xenial.tar.gz' against 'xenial.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'xenial.tar.gz'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-46o837s0/xenial", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-46o837s0/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 239, in main
    save_system_state(logdir)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-46o837s0/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 131, in save_system_state
    scrub_sources=True)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-46o837s0/DistUpgrade/apt_clone.py", line 149, in save_state
    self._write_state_installed_pkgs(sourcedir, tar)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-46o837s0/DistUpgrade/apt_clone.py", line 203, in _write_state_installed_pkgs
    import lsb_release
ImportError: No module named 'lsb_release'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 480, in add_to_existing
    self.write(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 433, in write
    block = f.read(1048576)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-46o837s0/xenial", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-46o837s0/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 239, in main
    save_system_state(logdir)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-46o837s0/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 131, in save_system_state
    scrub_sources=True)
```

Log File

```
2017-05-26 19:37:22,056 ERROR not handled exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4vs1duge/xenial", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4vs1duge/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 239, in main
    save_system_state(logdir)

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4vs1duge/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 131, in save_system_state
    scrub_sources=True)

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4vs1duge/DistUpgrade/apt_clone.py", line 149, in save_state
    self._write_state_installed_pkgs(sourcedir, tar)

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4vs1duge/DistUpgrade/apt_clone.py", line 203, in _write_state_installed_pkgs
    import lsb_release

ImportError: No module named 'lsb_release'

2017-05-26 19:37:22,057 DEBUG running apport_crash()
2017-05-26 19:37:22,263 DEBUG enabling apt cron job
```

Running `lsb_release -a`

```
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-3.0-amd64:cxx-3.0-noarch:cxx-3.1-amd64:cxx-3.1-noarch:cxx-3.2-amd64:cxx-3.2-noarch:cxx-4.0-amd64:cxx-4.0-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-3.1-amd64:desktop-3.1-noarch:desktop-3.2-amd64:desktop-3.2-noarch:desktop-4.0-amd64:desktop-4.0-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:graphics-2.0-amd64:graphics-2.0-noarch:graphics-3.0-amd64:graphics-3.0-noarch:graphics-3.1-amd64:graphics-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.2-amd64:graphics-3.2-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.1-amd64:graphics-4.1-noarch:languages-3.2-amd64:languages-3.2-noarch:languages-4.0-amd64:languages-4.0-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:multimedia-3.2-amd64:multimedia-3.2-noarch:multimedia-4.0-amd64:multimedia-4.0-noarch:multimedia-4.1-amd64:multimedia-4.1-noarch:printing-3.2-amd64:printing-3.2-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch:qt4-3.1-amd64:qt4-3.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

Comment: how have you tried to upgrade?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: @MichaelBay: I don't know that that will work in this case, they seem to be encountering some sort of bug. Given that the release is no longer supported I don't know what to do about this. But does it get special status in terms of upgrading issues given that it has an ESM available for it.

Answer (score 2):

Found problem was due to version of `lsb_release` installed.

Running from terminal

```
python /usr/bin/lsb_release
```

Or

```
python2.7 /usr/bin/lsb_release
```

are both fine

While

```
python3 /usr/bin/lsb_release
```

Or

```
python3.4 /usr/bin/lsb_release
```

gave

```
ImportError: No module named 'lsb_release'
```

I downgraded `lsb_release` back to `4.1+Debian11ubuntu8` version using Synaptic Package Manager to fix the issue.